# How to write to log from vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am attempting to develop an extension with a language-server for VSCode. I am trying to figure out how to write text to log from language-server part of the extension. console.log produces nothing

Answer (score 60):

Just as an update, you can use [`vscode.window.createOutputChannel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createOutputChannel) to create the output container and then write to it with the [`appendLine`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OutputChannel) method.

```js
    //Create output channel
    let orange = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("Orange");

    //Write to output.
    orange.appendLine("I am a banana.");
```

[image: Results of creating output channel.]

Comment: This works, but I can't get it to switch to the `Orange` channel when appending lines. Other extensions seem to have a way to switch channels automatically.

Comment: This reply is a little late, but you can call `orange.show();` to make the output channel show up.

Comment: @Kugelblitz wow thanks, i spent hours looking for the debugging window lol

Comment: That lying banana/orange! :)

Answer (score 15):

Just open vscode and go to menu "Help"->"Toggle Developer Tools" and the console is displayed on rigth window.

Comment: The output channel thing above flat doesn't work for me.  This did.

Answer (score 8):

On server side try using connection.console.log.

```
// Create a connection for the server. The connection uses 
// stdin / stdout for message passing
let connection: IConnection = createConnection(process.stdin, process.stdout);
connection.console.log(`Console test.`);
```

The message with show in Debug console on client side.

For client side simple console.log works well for me.

Comment: IConnection is a part of [vscode-languageserver-node](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node) module.

Answer (score 7):

You have to set an `outputChannelName` property on the client options inside the client extension code:

```
let clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
  outputChannelName: 'XYZ Language Server',
};
```

Once you've done that you can use `console.log()` and it will be shown in the VSCode extension output panel.

Comment: This is a bit unclear: where do I put this, why would I use it instead of the `createOutputChannel` instructions from the other answer, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The Language Server Protocol supports logging, use the notification [window/logMessage](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#window_logMessage) to send log messages from the server, VS Code will display the server's log in the output panel, in the channel corresponding to the language client that started the server.

Answer (score 1):

#### Thanks guys!

```js
export let config: any = {};
export function getConfig() {

    //debug
    config.debug = workspace.getConfiguration().get('VBI.debug');
    config.debugToChannel = workspace.getConfiguration().get('VBI.debugToChannel'); //Instead into dev-tools-console

    return config;
}




/**
 * @param cat Type String --> define Cathegory [info,warn,error]
 * @param o   Rest Parameter, Type Any --> Data to Log
 */
export let info = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("VBI-Info");
export function log(cat: string, ...o: any) {

    function mapObject(obj: any) {

        switch (typeof obj) {
            case 'undefined':
                return 'undefined';

            case 'string':
                return obj;

            case 'number':
                return obj.toString;

            case 'object':
                let ret: string = '';
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
                    ret += (`${key}: ${value}\n`);
                }
                return ret;

            default:
                return obj; //function,symbol,boolean

        }

    }

    if (config.debug) {
        if (config.debugToChannel) {

            
            
            switch (cat.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'info':
                    
                    info.appendLine('INFO:');
                    o.map((args: any) => {
                        info.appendLine('' + mapObject(args));
                    });
                    info.show();
                    return;
                    
                case 'warn':
                    info.appendLine('WARN:');
                    o.map((args: any) => {
                        info.appendLine('' + mapObject(args));
                    });
                    info.show();
                    return;

                case 'error':
                    let err:string=''; 
                    info.appendLine('ERROR: ');
                    //err += mapObject(cat) + ": \r\n";
                    o.map((args: any) => {
                        err += mapObject(args);
                    });
                    info.appendLine(err);
                    vscode.window.showErrorMessage(err);//.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
                    info.show();
                    return;
                    
                default:
                    
                    info.appendLine('INFO-Other:');
                    info.appendLine(mapObject(cat));
                    o.map((args: any) => {
                        info.appendLine('' + mapObject(args));
                    });
                    info.show();
                    return;
            }

        }
        else {
            switch (cat.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'info':
                    console.log('INFO:', o);
                    return;
                case 'warn':
                    console.log('WARNING:', o);
                    return;
                case 'error':
                    console.log('ERROR:', o);
                    return;
                default:
                    console.log('log:',cat, o);
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

tests:

```js
import * as func from './functions';
import { config } from './functions';
func.getConfig();
let text = `debugToChannel:${config.debugToChannel}\n`;

            func.log('info','vbi-format',text);
            func.log('warn','vbi-format',text);
            func.log('error','vbi-format',text);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).