# How to tell if VSCode language extension is running (logging/debugging)?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, logging, vscode-extensions

I am putting together a very basic VSCode "language server" following their [demo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/f7c3737b6e116c12e896c71dfe8e59ff3e8b9f3d/lsp-sample). The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/teamtreesurf/link/tree/make/code). I basically just want to do basic "tab completion" for now, but trying to get a simple hello-world example running and I'm not sure if my extension is even running, or how to debug/log in it. Some notes:

- There is a `client` directory, where the extension starts.
- The top-level `package.json` has `"main": "./client/out/extension"`, which is compiled TypeScript output.
- There is a `server` directory, which has the logic for the tab completion.
- I put `client.info('hello')` in the client `client/src/extension.ts` file, but got no output.

[image]

*(the screen in the back left is the extension test runner, the screen on the right is the extension source code repo).*

What am I missing? How do I debug that everything is running? How do I log to the "console", and where will it show up? Can I do anything like `alert('foo')` like you can in the browser? (Maybe to test that the test runner shows the completion)? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, I've never written a full extension. I will say that I did build the syntax highlighter part of the extension, and that loads fine in the test runner.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085330/how-to-write-to-log-from-vscode-extension) but still not seeing the output anywhere. Not sure if I'm just looking in the wrong place, or my extension isn't actually running properly.

[image]

Maybe these workers getting blocked is a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Client",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"],
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/client/out/**/*.js"],
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
      "preLaunchTask": {
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "watch"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is this the solution or just an addition/edit of the question

Comment: how can you debug/try the extension without a launch.json